# Are there radial basis functions $\phi_n(x)$ which can be factored as $f_n(x) x^{\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<1$ and $n>0$?

Tags: numerics, basis-set

I am looking for a set of radial basis functions $\phi_n(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^+=[0;\infty[$ which satisfy some othogonality condition

$$ \int x \phi_n(x) \phi_{n'}^*(x) dx =\delta_{nn'}$$

and "behave" like some (fractional) polynomial  $x^{\alpha}$, by which I mean they can be analytically factored as $\phi_n(x)=f_n(x) x^{\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<1$ and $n>0$ and where $f_n$ is an "uncomplicated" function, i.e. without singularities on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and at least a few times differentiable. Of course, this would mean that $\phi_n(0)=0$ so I am allowing one constant term $\phi_0(x)=\mathrm{const}$.

The idea here is that given the expansion $g(x)=\sum_n c_n \phi_n(x)$ for some $g$ which is compatible with the basis set and for which $c_0=0$, we have $g(x)x^{-\alpha}=\sum_n c_n f_n(x)$ whithout having numerical issues near $x=0$.

Comment: The problem sounds a bit underspecified to me. Without singularity won't work, as you need negative values in the chosen interval, otherwise you won't get orthogonality.   Next, regarding the orthogonality condition -- why you need the additional "x" in the integral? If you are looking for standard orthogonal polynomials on $[0,\infty]$ you can have a look at the Laguerre or half-open Hermite polynomials.